# Share link without http:// scheme on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

We have an application for iPad that shares a link of part of the application through Facebook. The link shared must open that iPad app when clicked on link. This has link url like AppName://. This link not supported on Facebook to share through Share Link as not compliant url scheme. Being completely new and having client to reply about the feasibility, can the requirement be fulfilled Facebook App or other way if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by sharing link (with 'http' url scheme) on Facebook of a page that has javascript to load url with iPad open app scheme. Same as below:

```
<html><head></head><body onload="OpeniPadApp()">

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function OpeniPadApp() {
         window.location = 'AppName://';
     }
 </script>

</body></html>
```

That's it. When the link opens, page load event fires that redirect to open iPad app.